# __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'name'

Tags: python, class, init

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *

pygame.init()

class levelClass(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
```

this init name of window

```
def makeWindow(self):
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800,800))
    pygame.display.set_caption(self.name)

def drawName(self):
    myfont = pygame.font.SysFont("monospace", 25)
    label = myfont.render(self.name, 1, (255,0,0))
    screen.blit(label, (400,400))

level = levelClass('Level 0')
while True:
    level.__init__()
    level.drawName()
    level.makeWindow()
    for event in pygame.event:
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.exit()
            sys.close()
    pygame.display.update()
```

this will create a window with name Level 0 and write this on window, but i see this error:
**init**() missing 1 required positional argument: 'name'

Comment: You are misusing `__init__()`. `__init__()` is called automatically on instance creation, which is done in the line: `level = levelClass('Level 0')`

Comment: You call `level.__init__()` with no arguments.  Why are you calling `__init__` at all?  It is automatically called when you create the instance with `level = levelClass('level 0')`.

Comment: As a guess, are you coming from Objective C? If so, think of Python as always using the convenience single-stage constructors (like `mystr = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:url]`) rather than two-stage constructors (like `mystr = [NSString alloc]; [mystr initWithContentsOfURL:url];`. Then it all makes sense.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need to call `__init__(...)` explicitly, when you create the object:

```
level = levelClass('Level 0')
```

it implicitly calls `__init__(...)` with the argument "Level 0", so you don't need to do it in the `while` loop.

The `__init__` method is roughly what represents a constructor in Python, so it is supposed to be executed just one time, when you create the object.

**Edit:**
In conclusion, you must not call `__init__()`, when you create the object:

```
level = levelClass('Level 0')
```

it is called implicitly, so to correct your problem, delete this line:

```
level.__init__()
```

Answer (score 1):

`levelClass.__init__` is defined like this:

```
def __init__(self, name):
```

so it requires a name argument.

So either eliminate the call to

```
level.__init__()
```

(why do you need it anyway?) or change

```
level.__init__()
```

to

```
level.__init__(name)
```

for some value of `name`. You would use this only if you wished to change `level.name` with each iteration of the `while-loop`. This might be useful if there was more stuff going on in the `__init__` method than just setting

```
self.name = name
```

-- for example, if `__init__` were loading a different map for each level. If all that `__init__` is doing is setting the name, then you don't need to call `__init__` to change the `name` attribute; you could just set it directly:

```
level.name = somename
```

---

PS. When an instance (e.g. `level`) calls the method `__init__` like this:

```
level.__init__(somename)
```

Python calls

```
levelClass.__init__(level, somename)
```

Thus `self` is set to the value `level`, and `name` is set to `somename`.